# ¿es posible añadir en jQuery addClass() a una variable?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo una variable que cuenta filas de una tabla:

```
var rowCount = $('table > tbody > tr').length;
```

Que posteriormente muestro un mensaje con "Hay N filas", done pongo el número en negrita y en un color, usando una clase CSS.

Para eso uso

```
$("#msg").html("Hay <span class='bo'>" + rowCount + "</span> filas");
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible no usar span y usar directamente addClass() sobre la variable.

Gracias!!

Comment: Creo que no, `addClass()` solo se puede usar para elementos en html.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método `addClass` de jquery en el elemento `#msg` para añadir la clase al elemento en el que estas insertando el `html` y así evitar añadir un `span` si es lo que deseas.

Esta solución depende de si los estilos que tenga previamente `#msg` no se rompan añadiendo la clase de CSS.

Así.

```javascript
$("#msg").addClass('bo').html("Hay " + rowCount + " filas");
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar el `span` para que solo el numero esté en negritas es la mejor práctica que puedes aplicar, ya que para esto es ese elemento

> ### **Definición**
>
> `span` - *abarcar*. Es un contenedor en línea. Sirve para aplicar estilo al texto o agrupar elementos en línea.
>
> [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/span)

Aplicarle el estilo en negritas al puro numero sin rodearlo con un `span` dentro de la misma linea lo veo muy difícil.

También tienes la opción de utilizar otro `tag`, como por ejemplo [`<var>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_var.asp) y definir el estilo de esta en tu `css`.

```css
var{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```js
$("#msg").html("Hay <var>" + rowCount + "<var> filas");
```